# Micronaut Data JDBC - Save a list of entries & update already existing entries

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, groovy, micronaut

I'm working on a REST API (Micronaut / Groovy), and I want to implement a POST request that saves a list of entries into a MySQL database.

Right now I'm using the saveAll() function from Micronaut Data, but the problem with saveAll() is that it fails if there is already an entry in the database table with the same fields (Unique Constraint).

The ideal solution for me is to update already existing entries and create non-existing entries.

But I don't know what is the right approach to handle this problem.

```
@Transactional
void saveNormalized(List<NormalizedValue> normalizedValues){
    normalizedRepository.saveAll(normalizedValues)
}
```

```
@Validated
@JdbcRepository(dialect= Dialect.MYSQL)
interface NormalizedRepository extends CrudRepository<NormalizedValue, Long> {
}
```

Comment: Can you add your entity `NormalizedValue` and DB Schema?

Comment: Why is that important?

Answer (score 0):

With the information provided, only thing that I can suggest is to split your `normalizedValues` list into two groups. Those that do not have an `id` and those that do. Then for the ones without `id` use `saveAll` and for the ones with `id` use `updateAll`.

For example:

```
@Transactional
void saveNormalized(List<NormalizedValue> values) {
    def hasId = values.groupBy{ it.id != null }
    normalizedRepository.updateAll(hasId[true])
    normalizedRepository.saveAll(hasId[false])
}
```